# How to converting text string into date format

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a column with values like this: "Wednesday 7 January 2015". How can I convert this into a date like "1/7/2015"? I've tried the `Date` and `DateValue` functions, but they did not work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999))
```

and give this cell a *Date* format:

[image]

Comment: thanks! it worked, now i have a bizzare problem where if i copy and paste this for the entire column it only converts the first cell but not the rest, cell values in the formula do change.

Comment: basically i get something like this :

Comment: Wednesday 7 January 2015 1/7/2015
Tuesday 6 January 2015 1/7/2015
Monday 5 January 2015 1/7/2015
Sunday 4 January 2015 1/7/2015

Comment: Make sure you set *Calculation* to *Automatic*

Comment: Thamks so much! Working now. Very useful for future data manipulations :)

Comment: @S.Papkov  You are quite welcome!